# p-groups with isomorphic automophism groups.

Tags: gr.group-theory

Given a finite group $H$, How can one prove that the equation $Aut(X)=H$ has only finitely many solutions in the class of finite p-groups. (This would be the case if the divisibility conjecture is true : that is the order of a p-group divides the order of its automorphism group)

Comment: Are you sure that your assertion is true?

Comment: @Fernando Muru, I'm not sure, I just think that is true.

Comment: You could edit your question accordingly, adding also the reasons why you think it's true.

Comment: See H. K. Iyer, On solving the equation Aut(X)=G, Rocky Mountain Journal of Mathematics 9 (1979), no. 4, 653--670. The paper can be accessed here: 

http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS/Repository/1.0/Disseminate?handle=euclid.rmjm/1250129106&view=body&content-type=pdf_1

Comment: Your divisibility conjecture is not true. The order of $C_2\times C_2$ does not divide the order of its automorphism group $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{F}_2)\cong S_3$.

Comment: @ Alex Bartel : I'm sorry, for the divisibility conjecture we have to assume that our p-group has order at least p^3. This conjecture is trivially false for p-groups of order p and p^2, for the cyclic one, the automorphism groups have order p-1.  and a group of order p^2 is either cyclic, so its automorphism group has order p(p-1), or is elementary abelian, so its automorphism group is Gl(2, p) which has p (p-1)^2 elements.       

Comment: @Primoz : Thank you so much.  Just I note that an affirmative answer to my question follows from THEOREM 2.10. in Iyer's paper.  This result is due to K. H. Hyde : "On the order of the automorphism group of a finite group, Ph.D.Thesis, University of Utah, 1969.
 

Comment: @Primoz or OP - add as an answer?